# proving that $-1$ and $1$ are the only units in $Z$, using the given axioms

Tags: abstract-algebra, integers, axioms

I've made a fresh start at learning abstract algebra, using the book [Abstract Algebra: An Inquiry-Based Approach](https://www.crcpress.com/Abstract-Algebra-An-Inquiry-Based-Approach/Hodge-Schlicker-Sundstrom/p/book/9781466567061). (I have in the past made a start with another book, so this isn't my first time seeing some of this stuff.)

I've kind of hit a snag on one of the proof questions (called "activities" in this book) in the first chapter which appears to require more assumptions/axioms for its proof than have been provided.

**I want to make sure if I do actually need the extra axioms or whether it's possible to complete the proof without them.**

---

In the book, the integers are first defined by appealing to common knowledge:

> The set of integers, denoted $\mathbb{Z}$, contains the whole numbers
>   and their opposites (or negatives); that is $\mathbb{Z} =
>  \{...,-3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3,...\}$

And then the following **arithmetic axioms** are listed:

- Closure of integers under addition and multiplication
- Commutativity of addition and multiplication
- Associativity of addition and multiplication
- Distributivity of multiplication over addition
- The integer $0$ is an additive identity
- The integer $1$ is a multiplicative identity
- Every integer $a$ has an additive inverse.

*(It's pretty standard stuff, I haven't bothered writing out the exact statements above.)*

And a bit later<sup>1</sup>, the **ordering axioms** ($a$, $b$ and $c$ represent arbitrary integers):

- Trichotomy: Exactly one of $a < b, b < a, a = b$ is true.
- Transitivity: $a < b$ and $b < c \implies a < c$
- Translational invariance: If $a < b$, then $a + c < b + c$
- Scaling: If $a < b$ and $c > 0$, then $a c < b c$.

The activity I'm having trouble with is the one in the red outline:
[image]

Basically you need to prove that $1$ and $-1$ are the only *units* in $\mathbb{Z}$ (numbers that have multiplicative inverses).

---

So far, neither has the axiom:

$0 \neq 1$

been mentioned by the book (although I realise they're implicitly assuming it), nor the

**well-ordering principle**

(every non-empty subset of the integers bounded below has a smallest element).

---

**I just want to check whether my understanding is correct: to give a rigorous proof of (c), I need to assume both those axioms.**

In particular, $0 \neq 1$ lets me prove (using the other axioms) that<sup>2</sup> $0 < 1$, and to prove the non-existence of a purported *unit* $a$ greater than zero<sup>3</sup> other than $1$, I need to show that either $a$ or its multiplicative inverse is between $0$ and $1$, but there are no integers between $0$ and $1$ - to prove which I need the well-ordering property - which means $a$ can't exist.

---

<sup>1: All of this being interspersed with several "activities" which is the "inquiry-based approach"'s version of exercises.</sup>

<sup>2: I haven't thought through whether knowing $0 < 1$ is necessary in order to finish the proof, but I believe I do need $0$ and $1$ to be distinct.</sup>

<sup>3: This is "without loss of generality" because if $a$ is a *unit*, so is $-a$.</sup>

Comment: If $0=1$ was allowed (arguably your fourth and fifth axioms together say they are distinct) then this would only be one element of your ordered ring since any element $r$ would then satisfy $r=r1=r0=r(1-1)=r-r=0$; this element would therefore be $1$ and $-1$ so they are units and there are no others - I doubt that was intended.  But you must have more for $\mathbb Z$, such there being no element $x$ with $0 \lt x \lt 1$, since $\mathbb Q$ and $\mathbb R$ also satisfy your ten axioms

Comment: I did realise that $0 = 1$ meant there was only element but - as you said - that couldn't have been the intention. But I'm not sure if the 4th and 5th axioms imply $0 \neq 1$. In any case, even after assuming $0 \neq 1$. I should've realised - as you pointed out - that the same axioms are satisfied by $\mathbb{Q}$ and $\mathbb{R}$ so clearly something was missing. 
Although I like the book's approach (after the one day I spent with it),  I'm not sure if missing the additional axiom was intended (maybe it's a feature of the inquiry-based approach?) or an oversight by the authors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you definitely need more axioms.  The listed axioms are also true for the rational numbers, for instance, which have lots more units.  You also can't prove $0\neq 1$, since a singleton set would also satisfy all the axioms (although in that case, you technically wouldn't be *wrong* in saying that $1$ and $-1$ are the only units).  Also conspicuously missing is associativity of addition and multiplication, which probably allows some very weird examples (though if you assume your well-ordering axiom, that might be enough to prove associativity).

Comment: Oops, I left out the associativity axioms by mistake! I am intrigued by your comment that the well-ordering axiom might be enough to prove associativity. Are you sure that's true?

Comment: I'm not sure, I haven't thought through it carefully.  But the well-ordering axiom is _very_ strong and can be used to prove things like commutativity and associativity in slightly different contexts such as Peano arithmetic.

Answer (score 1):

It's surprising that one needs ordering to see this, but it's pretty much the case. If $2^{-1}$ were an integer $k$, you can certainly deduce that $k$ must be a positive integer. But then how can $2\cdot k = 1$ when $2k$ is greater than $k$?